# Argument of type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindManyOptions<User>'

Tags: node.js, nestjs

```
create(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = this.repo.create({ email, password });

    return this.repo.save(user);
}

findOne(id: number) {
    return this.repo.findOneBy({id});
}

find(email: string) {
    return this.repo.find({ email });
}
}
```

I am trying to pass string to the find method, but it shows this error. Also, this message follows:

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'email' does not exist in type 'FindManyOptions<User>'.ts(2345)

Comment: `{ where: { email } }`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `where` instead of just using email. You can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71798172/20250421).

`return this.repo.find({ where:{email} });`